# Acumatica error: "The multi-part identifier could not be bound" On Customized Field that is not a mutli-part identifier

Tags: c#, sql-server, acumatica

I have seen this "*The multi-part identifier could not be bound*" error before, but this time it is giving it on my custom field which is simply a string.

When I run this with the VS2022 debugger running, the error is not caught, so I am not sure where it is even happening in my code. This is the workflow:

1. create an Opportunity.
2. From opportunity, create a “Project Quote”

[image: Create Project Quote]

3. Convert Project Quote to Project:
   [image: Convert Quote]
4. Add a row on the revenue budget tab for the project:
   [image: Add Revenue and Save]

And this generates this error:

[image: Error]

The field it references ***DOES*** exist in the CROpportunity database, and it is a custom field that is not multipart. It also is not null, but has a value:

[image: SQL database]

As I said, when I run this inside of the VS2022 debugger, I do not get a break when this error is thrown, so I don't even know where the error happens, or what the values for this DAC are when it gets thrown. Apparently Acumatica is trapping this and handling it via a popup box without letting me get to it.

**How can I debug this if I can't get a breakpoint?**

**[EDIT To Try Patrick Chen's Suggestion]**

My DAC definition for the field is:

```
    #region UsrAuthorizedByContact 
    [PXDBString(256)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Authorized by Contact")]
    public virtual string UsrAuthorizedByContact { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrAuthorizedByContact : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrAuthorizedByContact> { }
    #endregion
```

My SQL Server Definition is:

[image: SQL nvarchar(256)]

And my Database script is defined as:
[image: Customization Database script]

Does that look correct?

[NEW EDIT FOR RICK'SSUGGESTION]

I tried this in my DAC definitions, and get the same result.
(Is this what you mean?)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.FS;
using PX.Data.ReferentialIntegrity.Attributes;
using PX.Objects.CM.Extensions;
using American.ASG.DAC;
using American.Descriptor;

namespace American.DAC
{
    public class CROpportunityExt : PXCacheExtension<CROpportunity>
    {

         
        #region UsrAuthorizedByContact
        [PXDBString(BqlField = typeof(CROpportunityStandaloneExt.usrAuthorizedByContact))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Authorized by Contact")]
        public virtual string UsrAuthorizedByContact { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrAuthorizedByContact : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrAuthorizedByContact> { }
        #endregion

    }

    public class CROpportunityStandaloneExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.CROpportunity>
    {

        #region UsrAuthorizedByContact
        [PXDBString(256)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Authorized by Contact")]
        public virtual string UsrAuthorizedByContact { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrAuthorizedByContact : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrAuthorizedByContact> { }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: You can use SQL Profiler or Extended events to capture both the SQL queries and error messages.

Comment: Common causes for this message: (1) The table is not included in the FROM clause. (2) The table is included in a subquery, but is not directly visible where referenced in an outer query. (3) The table is included with an alias, but the column reference is prefixed with the original table name instead of the assigned alias. (My money would be on #3.)

Comment: And the problem is, Acumatica generates the SQL command, not me. Checking the command in the SQL profiler, seems to indicate that a JOIN is missing... but since I don't create this SQL command, I am not sure what to do about it... But thanks for your help! @DavidBrowne-Microsoft and TN

Comment: There are two CROpportunity DACs. One is a projection of the other one. They're in different namespaces. Hence when adding custom field in this table. Two DACs are altered automatically. When you added your custom field. Did you use the UI wizard or manually by code ?

Comment: @Rick Please check the above for edits I made, trying to follow your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference (like for future me, who forgets...)

The issue here was that PMProject Extends Contract, as can be seen by looking at the source code (via ScreenID sm204570):

```
using PX.Objects.CT;    
public partial class PMProject : Contract, IAssign, PX.SM.IIncludable
```

Because of this, it seems my custom fields have to be added to both PMProject and Objects.CT.Contract, and (as Patrick Chen said above) they need to be defined the same.

So, in addition to:

```
public class PMProjectExt : PXCacheExtension<PMProject>
{

    #region UsrAuthorizedByContact 
    [PXDBString(256)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Authorized by Contact")]
    public virtual string UsrAuthorizedByContact { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrAuthorizedByContact : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrAuthorizedByContact> { }
    #endregion

}
```

I also needed:

```
public class ContractExt : PXCacheExtension<Contract>
{
    #region UsrAuthorizedByContact
    [PXDBString(256)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Authorized by Contact")]
    public virtual string UsrAuthorizedByContact { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrAuthorizedByContact : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrAuthorizedByContact> { }
    #endregion

}
```

I tried it with both **[PXDBString(256)]** and **[PXDBString]** and either seemed to work. I kept it as [PXDBString(256)] since that is how it is defined in the SQL database.

If a field were missing from either of them, I got the error. With both defined, it appears to be running fine.

FWIW.

Comment: Now I'm more confused. What's Contract/Project got to do with CROpportunity table?

Comment: @Rick - I am confused about that as well. All I can figure is during the save, within the Base method , they must be updating other DACs, and the projection isn't being used, which causes the mismatch. But that is only a guess. And when I added the above to my code, the error went away. If anyone can explain it, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is a problem with your DAC extension definition versus your SQL column definition.

Comment: Well, that makes sense, but check out my Edit. I don't think that's it... or am I missing something? @Patrick-Chen

Comment: Have you added the field to the UI?  If so, delete and re-add.  Make sure that it is a text field.

Comment: Yes. That wasn't the issue in this case. I discovered that since Project actually extends Contracts, I had to add the fields to Contracts as well. (Maybe had I used the GUI it would have done it automatically? IDK. But that seems to be my issue.) Thanks for looking at the problem with me!